# Transfer parameter from one controller to another in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to transfer one parameter (string) that I create in one controller to another controller. Till today I used global variable and it worked fine, but now a few users use the application, so I can't verify that the parameter was not rewrite by other users. The parameter is unique. I tried to use HttpContext.Session, but cannot be used in another controller (just returns null).

Do you have any idea how to do it?

And also, is it possible to use one  instance of HttpContext.Session in different controllers?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share your current code snippet? How you are trying to parameter from one controller to another could you include that snippet so that it can be understood correctly.

Comment: Just regular global variable, added to controllers with dependency injection

Comment: For example if I have controller of name `Confirmation(int? id)` which takes one parameters, then I can call it from another controller like this: `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Confirmation), new { id = 12});` It will pass the `id` as of value `12`

Comment: I can't verify that user receives his id in the second controller, I want to verify that user receives his id, not any id

Comment: Share your current code and then need to have a look, your explanation cannot visualize your code accordingly.

Comment: Make sure you use an instance of the class and make variable public.

Comment: @jdweng I haven't problem with syntax, only logic problem

Comment: `I used global variable and it worked fine` no it didn't you just haven't realized your application was always broken because it wasn't being used.

Comment: `I tried to use HttpContext.Session, but cannot be used in another controller` that's wrong. A session is a *user* session. It's available as long as the user session is active. If it's null, it means there's no user any more. You should investigate why `Session` is null. Are you actually redirecting to that other *route*? Or trying to treat a controller as if it was a singleton?

Comment: A controller is created to server a single request and gets disposed right after the request is finished. The only way to pass data from one request (not controller, it's *requests* that are actually active) to another is to pass it as part of the request or through the Session storage. That Session is provided by the middleware when it creates the Controller instance. The middleware knows which session data to use by inspecting the user's session cookie. Without a session cookie there's no session

Answer (score -1):

Create `global static` variable inside `controller` class.

```
public class HomeController
{
    public static string object_name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in another controller use `DependencyResolver` to initialize `HomeController`

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly HomeController homeController = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<HomeController>();
    
    homeController.object_name = "" //Set value
    var a = homeController.object_name; //Get value
}
```

Comment: What happens if the site is used by *two* users? This won't even work during testing. That's what the OP did to get into this mess `I used global variable and it worked fine, but now a few users use the application`

Comment: Yes, It is absolutely the same I have now